# Importing files in Python from __init__.py

Tags: python, import, module

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
app/
  __init__.py
  foo/
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    __init__.py
```

a.py, b.py and c.py share some common imports (logging, os, re, etc). Is it possible to import these three or four common modules from the `__init__.py` file so I don't have to import them in every one of the files?

Edit: My goal is to avoid having to import 5-6 modules in each file and it's not related to performance reasons.

Comment: If you want to do this for performance reasons, don't worry - importing already loaded modules is super-fast (a simple dict lookup on sys.modules).

Comment: Edited question to clarify my motives.

Comment: The stated goal kinda reduces code readability, don't you think?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that Python has no package scope, only module scope. Packages really aren't first-class constructs in Python, they were sort of bolted on later, and all they really do is allow dotted notation of modules. Maybe create a PEP for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they have to be put in each module's namespace, so you have to import them somehow (unless you pass `logging` around as a function argument, which would be a weird way to do things, to say the least).

But the modules are only imported once anyway (and then put into the `a`, `b`, and `c` namespaces), so don't worry about using too much memory or something like that.

You can of course put them into a separate module and import *that* into each `a`, `b`, and `c`, but this separate module would still have to be imported everytime.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using a common file such as `include.py`, but it goes against recommended practices because it involves a wildcard import. Consider the following files:

```
app/
    __init__.py
foo/
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    include.py <- put the includes here.
    __init__.py
```

Now, in `a.py`, etc., do:

```
from include import *
```

As stated above, it's not recommended because wildcard-imports are discouraged.

Comment: +1 for wildcards.

A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds.  The inability to group related imports sensibly is a python wart; thus, it must yield to the wildcard.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but **don't do it**. Seriously, don't. But if you still want to know how to do it, it'd look like this:

```
import __init__

re = __init__.re
logging = __init__.logging
os = __init__.os
```

I say not to do it not only because it's messy and pointless, but also because your package isn't really supposed to use `__init__.py` like that. It's package initialization code.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's pointless. Some things you want to apply to all your code, e.g. `from future import unicode_literals`. Do I really have to put that in every file (and then forget some, resulting in hard-to-find bugs)?