# Importing Commonly Used Modules in Python

Tags: python, import

I usually need to import one or more identical modules to different py files, say

```
a.py
import sys
import os

b.py
import sys

c.py
import os
```

I don't want to import the same module again in different files, so I decide to write a importHelper.py and write the following

```
import sys
import os
```

So I just add import importHelper.py to a,b,c.py but outcome it does not work. (Cannot load the sys and os methods)

Is there any advice on how to import common modules on different files?

Thanks all for the reply.

Comment: You should `import` the dependency in all files that need it. That is the python way.

Comment: @EricUrban: That, in my mind, is an answer.

Comment: Use `from importHelper import *` in this situation.

Comment: So, although clumsy, I still need to import the dependencies for each file which needs them, right?

Comment: Remember that your code is also documentation. Be explicit with the dependencies as well. This type of "helper" only serves to confuse the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing files in Python from \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201115/importing-files-in-python-from-init-py)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Unnecessarily importing code into every module will get you to premature bloat. And [from the Python Style Guide:](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools.

As furas points out, modules are only imported once per session anyways (although you might reload one.)

And as Eric Urban says, it is convention, and expected. If you share your work with others, you will frustrate them to no end if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `from importHelper import *`. In this case you can use the same syntax, i.e. `sys.exit()` etc.

When you import it as `import importHelper`, you'll have to use it as `importHelper.sys.exit()`.

All in all, imported modules are merely labels (variable names) and can be used as such.

Comment: @Downvoters This is the only answer which actually addresses the question and says that it is possible. All other information is merely a guideline, and while it is a good guideline, it doesn't mean that one should religiously follow it. If one finds from import * useful and clean, it is his or her choice no matter what that guide says.

Comment: Thanks sashkello and all the feedbacks, I try from importHelper import *, and it does work! Thanks for the feedback! But I also agree that importing the code while needed is better to read for me and others

Answer (score 1):

You should import the dependency in all files that need it. That is the python way.

Comment: "That is the python way." is the worst explanation you can ever get. Therefore this is a bad answer. Explain why it is bad, otherwise it is meaningless.

Comment: See my answer for why this is bad.

Comment: @AaronHall Undownvoted your answer. This one is still bad because it is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Convention is not a non-reason.

Comment: Agreed, #NotAnAnswer.

Answer (score 1):

Python imports module only once even if you import that module in many files. It remeber modules imported before. So you can import as many times as you wish.

You should add `import module` in files which use that module to make code more readable for others (and for you).