# Python: How to import from an __init__.py file?

Tags: python, module

I'm building a website using the [Flask Framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/), in which I've got a folder in which I have some python files and an `__init__.py` script (I guess you would call this folder a module?). In the **init**.py file I've got a line saying:

```
db = Database(app)
```

I now want to use `db` in a different script which is in this folder. Normally I would do this using `from __init__ import db`, but that just doesn't seem right to do, let alone pythonic. Furthermore, since it is in the `__init__.py` file, I suppose it should somehow be initialised for the whole folder/module.

Does anybody know how I can use `db` from the `__init__.py` file? All tips are welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing files in Python from \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201115/importing-files-in-python-from-init-py)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

```
from . import db
```

Comment: if i use `from . import *` will it import everything inside `__init__.py` or all files inside the current folder?

Comment: How come `from .` knows to look inside `__init__.py`?

Comment: The `.` path is relative for current package. The `__init__.py` defines the current package and what to export.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__.py` files are automatically imported when you import the package they are in. For example, say the `__init__.py` is in a package called **foo**. When you import foo

```
import foo
from foo import *
import foo as ...
```

the `__init__` file gets called. And are you using Python 2 or 3? If you are using Python 3, you will need to use dynamic imports:

```
from * import __init__
```

In general, it is a bad practice to import from `__init__`, I would suggest trying to place this code in another file in the package.

Comment: This does not answer the question.