# How to import from __init__.py with Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following file structure for a Flask application:

```
myapplication/
  run.py
  myapplication/
    __init__.py
    views/
      __init__.py
      models.py
      ...
    templates/
    static/
```

And I have initialised the database in `myapplication/__init__.py` using SQLAlchemy. I want to import the database object in `models.py` though I'm unsure on how to do it.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282316/python-how-to-import-from-an-init-py-file) and tried to import the database object from `myapplication/__init__.py` using relative imports like this:

```
from ... import db
```

but I receive this error: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

So how to I get to the database object in `myapplication/__init__.py` for `models.py`? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an empty file called `__init__.py` to your `views` folder.
Also, I think you have a dot too many, i.e. it should be `from .. import db`. The first `.` references `views` and the second `.` will reference your `__init__.py`.

**EDIT**:
I had a look at the flask stuff I did myself ([freevle](https://github.com/Freevle/freevle)), and it seems like I never used a relative import to get at the database. In stead I used the app name, i.e. the name of the folder your top `__init__.py` is in. With freevle, I used `from freevle import db`. Would this work for you?

Comment: I did have the `__init__.py` in the views folder, just forgot to include it in the question, I just updated it. I tried using `from .. import db` but got the same error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm relatively new to creating packages with python. Would the package name just be the root folder that `__init__.py` is in?

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. I should have said app, not package.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `.` means current package; and the two dots mean "one package above" (they don't refer to file names); from [pep-0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/): _"Two or more leading dots give a relative import to the parent(s) of the current package, one level per dot after the first."_ - except in the special case of `__init__.py`