# How to import from the __init__.py in the same directory?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a module `rules` with the following structure:

```
rules
├── conditions.py
├── __init__.py
```

In the script `conditions.py`, I'd like to import a class called `RuleParserError` defined in `__init__.py`. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. (Following [Python: How to import from an __init__.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282316/python-how-to-import-from-an-init-py-file) I've tried

```
from . import RuleParserError
```

but this leads to an `ImportError: cannot import name RuleParserError` when trying to run `conditions.py` as `__main__`).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I see 'import from parent module' as an anti-pattern in Python. Imports should be the other way around. Importing from modules's `__init__.py` is especially problematic. As you noticed, importing module `foo.bar` from `foo/bar.py` involves importing `foo/__init__.py` first, and you may end up with a circular dependency. Adding a `print("Importing", __name__)` to your init files helps see the sequence and understand the problem.

I'd suggest that you moved the code you want to import in `conditions.py` from `__init__.py` to a separate lower-level module, and just import some names from that module in `__init__.py` to expose it at higher level.

Let's suppose that you had some `class Bar` in your `__init__.py`. I'd reorganize it the following way.

`__init__.py`:

```
from bar import Bar  # exposed at the higher level, as it used to be.
```

`bar.py`:

```
class Bar(object): ...
```

`conditions.py`:

```
from . import Bar  # Now it works.
```

Ideally an `__init__.py` should contain nothing but imports from lower-level modules, or nothing at all.

Comment: Can you include a directory tree showing where the files are in your example? I have tried several arrangements that seem to match what you describe, yet I get errors at every attempt, including "cannot import from partially initialized module," "no module named x," "attempted relative import with no known parent package," "cannot import name X from x (unknown location)."

Answer (score 9):

If you get

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

when you do like

```
import . from something
```

especially from the script executed, just try

```
from __init__ import something
```

Even though it could be problematic when there are many `__init__.py`s in `sys.path`, it would be helpful in some simple situaions.

Answer (score 0):

adding `__package__` on top the script

```
__package__ = "pkg.dir.dir"
```

resolving the issue

in this case

```
__package__ = "rules"
```