# APScheduler in flask with blueprints

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I am really struggling to work out how to get APScheduler running in my flask application.

App structure:

```
/app
├── project/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
├── app.py
```

app.py:

```
from project import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# set up blueprints
from .main import main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

# set up apscheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
scheduler.start()
```

main.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Flask
from . import scheduler
import time

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/schedule_test')
def schedule_test():
    scheduler.add_job(func=print_date_time, trigger="interval", seconds=3)

def print_date_time():
    print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'scheduler' from 'project' (/app/project/__init__.py)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but I can't work it out.

Edit: to be clear, the flask app runs fine when I remove the references to scheduler.

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? I´m facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should move following code from `__init__.py` to a separate Python file.

```
# set up apscheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
scheduler.start()
```

And then from that file, import `scheduler` and use it in your flask route.

Check this out:

[In Python, how to import from the __init__.py in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862042/in-python-how-to-import-from-the-init-py-in-the-same-directory)