# Use logger in python module/package?

Tags: python, logging, module, package

I have a python module and I want to set a logger to be available through the package.

1. I initiate the logger in the `__init__.py`
2. run the code with `python -m`
3. call a function in another file which needs logger from `__init__.py`

then I ger this error

```py
name 'logger' is not defined
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(msg)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from .code import log
log()
```

`code.py`:

```py
def log():
    logger.debug('test')
```

Comment: How (if at all) do you try to get the logger from `__init__.py` to where you're using it? Give a [mre] rather than a description.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you I added example . When I imported log and also I'm in a module which should have global variable I expect log function be able to see the logger.

Comment: *"I'm in a module which should have global variable"* - I'm not sure why you think that, that's **not** what defining it in `__init__.py` does.

Comment: Oh so how should i make a variable or function accessible through the module ? or i have to initiate the logger in every file of module ?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22282316/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1201115/3001761

Answer (score 0):

special thank to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) linked me to [Python: How to import from an __init__.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22282316/3001761)

the solution for having  a logger object through the module and don't initiate it in every file is :

```py
from . import logger
```